# I am learning python - Why Single quotation marks and code syntax is printed in my terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.8

### Why Single quotation marks and code syntax is printed in my terminal?

I wrote this code in my tutorial file:

```
var1 = "hello"
print(var1)
print(type(var1))

var2 = """Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers.

A peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked.

If Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers?

Where’s the peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked?
"""+"""              The""",var1,""" end"""
print(var2)
```

But when I run my code in my terminal
**It showed this:**

```
hello
<class 'str'>
('Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers.\n\nA peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked.\n\nIf Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers?\n\nWhere’s the peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked?\n              The', 'hello', ' end')
```

I wanted it to print this:

```
hello
<class 'str'>
Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers.

A peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked.

If Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers?

Where’s the peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked?
                  The hello end
```

I don't know how to fix it
**Please help me**

I have **3.8.6 Python** interpreter

Comment: `var2` is a tuple, not a string.  Use `+var1+` instead of `,var1,`.

Comment: Your question really has nothing to do with single vs. double quote marks. Both are acceptable ways to enter string literals in Python, but the Python shell defaults to single quotes when displaying them.

Comment: The answers are correct, but you may not understand why.  You have commas in the last line instead of "+".  The commas make it a 3-item tuple instead of a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```
var1 = "hello"
print(var1)
print(type(var1))

var2 = f"""Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers.

A peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked.

If Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers?

Where’s the peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked?
                    The {var1} end"""
print(var2)
```

result:

```
hello
<class 'str'>
Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers.

A peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked.

If Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers?

Where’s the peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked?
              The hello end
```

Comment: I am trying to solve it since tomorrow. Thank you, I understood it easily.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `var2` as a `tuple` rather than `str`. To see this for yourself, print the type of `var2`: `print(type(var2))`, you'll see that it is a `tuple`.

Python allows `tuple`s to be defined three ways:

1. `tuple(sequence)`
2. `(a, b, c)`
3. `a, b, c`

I avoid using the third syntax because it's very easy to edit unintentionally.

You need to replace the `,`s in `var2`'s declaration with `+`s in order to perform concatenation:

```py
var2 = """Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers.

A peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked.

If Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers?

Where’s the peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked?
"""+"""              The""" + var1 + """ end"""
```

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation done with the "+" operator so just change your last line to:

```
"""+"""              The """+var1+""" end"""
```

using "," means you are creating a tuple.